# Retrieve NgModel from NgForm

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm wondering if there's any way to retrieve the `NgModel` of a `FormControl` pulled from the `NgForm.controls` object of the form to which it belongs, or retreive the `NgModel`s from the form directly.

I have a form that, upon submit, I pass in as a parameter to a function I've defined:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" name="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFunc(myForm)">
  <input type="text" name="myInput" ngModel #myInput="ngModel">
</form>
```

```
myFunc(form) {
  form.controls // Gets me {[key: string]: FormControl}
}
```

I want to be able to set properties to my controls retrieved from the form (as `NgModel`s) and reference them in the template with:

```
{{ myInput.myProp }}
```

as opposed to:

```
{{ myInput.control.myProp }}
```

The overall goal being to set a custom property to each `NgModel` of a form when it's submitted, without having to pull that property from its underlying control. Is this possible and/or am I just going about it in the wrong way altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" name="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFunc(myForm)">
  <input type="text" name="myInput" ngModel #inp="ngModel">
  {{ inp.value }}
</form>
```

Comment: Well the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to set `inp.value` from the form passed into my submit function. At most I can set the property of the `FormControl` retrieved from `myForm.controls`, except then I can't access it as `inp.value`, but `inp.control.value`.

Comment: If you are trying to set the form's values in TypeScript, why not just using reactive forms API? You'll instantiate the form's model in the TypeScript code and will have full access to its controls.

Answer (score 0):

`#myInput="ngModel"` will get an ngModel, to access the native element you need an other template variable `#myInp`

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" name="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFunc(myForm)">
  <input #myInp type="text" name="myInput" ngModel #myInput="ngModel">
  {{myInp.getAttribute("my-attr")}}
</form>
```

You can set your custom attribute value this way:

```
@ViewChild("myInp") myInput: ElementRef;
myFunc(form) { 
    this.myInput.nativeElement.setAttribute('my-attr', 'attr: ' + form.value.myInput);
}
```